# pass an array as parameter to procedure without creating varray type in database

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

I need to pass an array from java to my procedure. I can do it easily by creating a varray type but my issue is I don't have permissions to create any objects.

Is there any way to pass an array as parameter to a procedure without using `CREATE TYPE`?

Comment: I think, instead of searching for and implementing workarounds, which might cause problems later, you should ask your DBA to grant you appropriate privileges or create objects him/herself.

Comment: i already asked and they denied privileges.so, is there any other way to do?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the structure of the array you need. Oracle has many built-in collections. Commonly used ones are

- `sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll` which is a nested table of `varchar2(1000)`
- `sys.odcivarchar2list` - `VARRAY(32767)` of `varchar2(4000)`
- `sys.odcinumberlist` - `VARRAY(32767)` of `number`
- `sys.odcidatelist` - take a wild guess :)

There are many other nested tables and VArrays already installed in the database. Run this query to see the list

```
select * from all_types
where typecode = 'COLLECTION'
/
```